# Changing UIButton colors when one is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, uibutton

I'm trying to make a button highlight purple when selected, and return all the other buttons to their deselected state.

I've created IBOutlets for each button:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *oneButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *twoButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *threeButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *fourButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *fiveButton;
```

Synthesized them:

```
@synthesize oneButton, twoButton, threeButton, fourButton, fiveButton;
```

And am trying to make a method that goes through all of them, highlighting the correct one and unhighlighting the rest. The only way I could get to work was the tedious way. I know there has to be an easier method.

Also this sets the background color of the deactivated buttons to lightGrayColor, but I want them to go back to their starting color which was the Mercury crayon color in interface.

```
- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {

if (self.oneButton == sender) {
    [self.oneButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [self.twoButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.threeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.fourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.fiveButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

} else if (self.twoButton == sender) {
    [self.oneButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.twoButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [self.threeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.fourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.fiveButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

} else if (self.threeButton == sender) {
    [self.oneButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.twoButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.threeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [self.fourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.fiveButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

} else if (self.fourButton == sender) {
    [self.oneButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.twoButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.threeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.fourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [self.fiveButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

} else if (self.fiveButton == sender) {
    [self.oneButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.twoButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.threeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.fourButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.fiveButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you do no longer need to synthesize your properties as long as you do not define both getters and setters.

Secondly, this should be easier.

```
NSArray *buttons = @[self.oneButton, ..., self.fiveButton];
[buttons makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) withObject:UIColor.lightGrayColor];
sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor;
```

Comment: Should it stay as an IBAction or switch to void? Currently getting error "property 'backgroundColor' not found on object of type '_strong id'

Comment: Yeah, that's the way to do it. You cannot access properties on `id` types, but you could have used `-setBackgroundColor:`.